# Memory error when running VBA

Tags: vba, memory, odbc

I am running an excel macro which pulls some data from a oracle database and display in a table format.

The macro runs fine for few minutes and then comes up with the below error:

"Microsoft ODBC Oracle can not allocate sufficient memory for proper operation. Please free up some memory and retry operation"

Please note that I am connecting to the database using DSN settings for Mirosoft ODBC for Oracle. Also please note that this macro was running fine XP with Oracle 10g client. I am facing this issue in Windows 7 (32 bit) with Oracle 11g client.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
Sub Refresh_Tables()

Dim intHour_of_Day As Variant

Sheets("Live Screen").Select
Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False



Sheets("Data2").Select
Range("Hour_of_Day").Select
intHour_of_Day = ActiveCell.Value

'MsgBox ("1")

Sheets("Data").Select
Range("G4").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Sheets("Data").Select
Range("U4").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

 'MsgBox ("2")

Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A25").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False


 'MsgBox ("3")
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If intHour_of_Day < 11 Then

     ' Refresh all Tables

Sheets("Data2").Select
Range("B10").Select

'MsgBox ("4")

Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("E10").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("H10").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("K10").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("N10").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False



Sheets("Data2").Select

'MsgBox ("5")

Range("Q9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("T9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("W9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("Z9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("AC9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

  ElseIf intHour_of_Day >= 11 And intHour_of_Day < 13 Then

Sheets("Data2").Select
Range("E10").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("H10").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("K10").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("N10").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Sheets("Data2").Select
Range("T9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("W9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("Z9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("AC9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

  ElseIf intHour_of_Day >= 13 And intHour_of_Day < 15 Then

Sheets("Data2").Select
Range("H10").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("K10").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("N10").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Sheets("Data2").Select
Range("W9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("Z9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("AC9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False


  ElseIf intHour_of_Day >= 15 And intHour_of_Day < 17 Then

  Sheets("Data2").Select
Range("K10").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("N10").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Sheets("Data2").Select
Range("Z9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("AC9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Else

'Update Running Total Tables

Sheets("Data2").Select
Range("N10").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Range("AC9").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

  End If


Sheets("Live Screen").Select
Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question would be improved by adding your actual code.

Comment: I have added the code. Can you please review and advise at the earliest?

Comment: Other than you seem to have a lot of separate queries there's really not much I could suggest.  If I'm dealing with Oracle I'm typically using ADO directly and not using QueryTables.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved after uninstall windows 7 32 bit and install windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Must have been some incompatibility. Please note that you could have been missing some libraries like .NET, and that your system could have just ran out of memory (as the message said). x86 can only use up to 4GB RAM (3.25GB effective), but x64 can use unlimited amounts of RAM (Microsoft caps Windows editions up to Professional to 128GB RAM).